# Sedra and Smith Microelectronics 7th edition Example 6.12

Tags: transistors, bjt

[image]

I quote from the book: "By examining the circuit, we conclude that the two transistors Q1 and Q2 cannot be simultaneously
conducting. Thus if Q1 is on, Q2 will be off, and vice versa."

Assume β = 100.

the question is: "why can't Q1 and Q2 be conducting at the same time?"

Comment: What are the conditions required for a transistor to begin conducting, and how might they be different for an NPN vs a PNP?

Comment: Because their bases and emitters are wired together?

Answer (score 4):

First of all 'B' or beta, which is the measure of a bjt transistors gain in a known circuit, is not a factor here based on your question. The emitters are tied together and referenced to ground via a 1K ohm resistor. A little research into NPN and PNP bjt transistors show they have a base-emitter turn-on voltage (forward) of about .55 to .65 vdc for the NPN and about -.55 to -.65 volts for the PNP.
 Based on your diagram if the base of both transistors was zero volts compared to ground, neither one would be on. If the base voltage rises above .55 volts or so Q1 begins to turn on,but Q2 is reverse biased so it is OFF.
 If we swap things around and input a -.55 volts to -.65 volts at the bases, then Q2 is ON and Q1 is reverse biased so it is OFF. This forward bias voltage needed creates a ~1.20 volt gap (centered around zero volts,or ground) inside of which neither transistor is ON. So logically, both transistors cannot be on at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

For Q2 (PNP) to conduct its b-e diode must be forward biased so its base voltage must be what with respect to its emitter voltage? Same question for Q1 (NPN), now note that the b-e voltages are the same because the emitters are connected together....

Regards, Dan.

Answer (score 1):

The technique required to solve the circuit you provided, and determine why Q1 and Q2 are not both conducting is to make an assumption about which transistor is conducting at the beginning of the analysis. Assume Q1 is conducting and Q2 is not (based on the 5V applied to the joint base resistor).

If Q1 is conducting then we can write a KVL equation from the base to the emitter, assuming a emitter base voltage drop of 0.7 V:
$$
-5~V + 10kI_B + V_{BE} + 1kI_E = 0 \\
10kI_B + 1k(1 + \beta)I_B = 4.3~V \\
I_B = 39~\mu A \\
I_E = (1 + \beta)I_B \approx 3.9~mA.
$$
So now we can determine the voltage at the emitter terminal, which is just:
$$
V_E = I_ER_E = 3.9~mA \cdot 1k\Omega = 3.9~V \\
V_C = 5~V \\
V_{CE} = 5~V - 3.9~V = 1.1~V
$$
Based on the assumptions made here it's clear that Q1 is conducting and is in the active region (\$V_{CE} > V_{BE})\$.

You can check the opposite assumption, but the result will be that the emitter-base diode in Q2 is reverse biased.

Answer (score 0):

Assume both are in active it implies[image: See currents in picture]

These 3 currents will be almost equal making the emitter voltage to go to 0. Since the base currents are almost same the base voltage is either just more than 5 or just less (don't care much here) though it is slightly more as the second transistor has more base current due to more emitter current, assuming matched beta, implying the B-E junction for npn is fwd bias but E-B junction for pnp is reverse biased also both of them have C-B junction reverse biased contradicting our assumption.